# Getting error while dealing with user defined classes in ipython console

Tags: python, ipython

First I should say that I am using Python 3.5.2.
I think something is wrong with **ipython** when I define my own classes.
So, when I run following code in standard python console, I get no error:

```
class A(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return self[item]
a = A({'x' : 1})
a['x']
```

But when I run the above code in **ipython** console, I get the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py in prefilter_lines(self, lines, continue_prompt)
    333                              for lnum, line in enumerate(llines) ])
    334         else:
--> 335             out = self.prefilter_line(llines[0], continue_prompt)
    336 
    337         return out

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py in prefilter_line(self, line, continue_prompt)
    308             return normal_handler.handle(line_info)
    309 
--> 310         prefiltered = self.prefilter_line_info(line_info)
    311         # print "prefiltered line: %r" % prefiltered
    312         return prefiltered

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py in prefilter_line_info(self, line_info)
    250         """
    251         # print "prefilter_line_info: ", line_info
--> 252         handler = self.find_handler(line_info)
    253         return handler.handle(line_info)
    254 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py in find_handler(self, line_info)
    257         for checker in self.checkers:
    258             if checker.enabled:
--> 259                 handler = checker.check(line_info)
    260                 if handler:
    261                     return handler

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py in check(self, line_info)
    414     def check(self, line_info):
    415         obj = self.shell.user_ns.get(line_info.ifun)
--> 416         if isinstance(obj, Macro):
    417             return self.prefilter_manager.get_handler_by_name('macro')
    418         else:

<ipython-input-1-cb6806333b6b> in __getattribute__(self, item)
      1 class A(dict):
      2     def __getattribute__(self, item):
----> 3         return self[item]
      4 

KeyError: '__class__'
```

Please help if you have any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like IPython is trying to access `a.__class__`, and failing. It's probably doing this as some kind of standard sweep of objects for diagnostic purposes. You'd get the same error in the regular Python console if you tried `print(a.__class__)`.

Your `__getattribute__` should have a fallback in case there's no entry in the dictionary matching the key. [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) recommends invoking the base class' `__getattribute__` method if you need to access an actual attribute. Something like:

```
class A(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in self:
            return self[item]
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
            #or possibly:
            #return super().__getattribute__(item)
            #... Depending on one's interpretation of "base class"

a = A({'x' : 1})
a['x']
print(a.__class__)
```

It might also make sense to override [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) instead of `__getattribute__`. That way, it is still possible to access all of the attributes of the object, without having to do any explicit checks for them in the function.

```
class A(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self:
            return self[item]
        else:
            raise AttributeError

a = A({'x' : 1})
a['x']
print(a.__class__)
```